# How can I insert a step into a Shortcut?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, siri, shortcuts-app

I've just started creating shortcuts for various things on my iPhone.  It's been useful, but I find that as I create longer and more complex scripts, I find the interface rather poor.  As an experienced programmer, I'd prefer to be able to do things like inserting a step into an already existing script.  So far, the only way I've found to do that is to delete all of the steps after the point I want to insert and then re-add them all back.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can firm touch and hold on a action and drag and drop it where ever it's appropriate in the workflow.

Comment: I should have known!  This makes the If/Otherwise/EndIf useful -- thanks!

Comment: I swear the first version of shortcuts I tried allowed directly inserting actions at a selected point, but yeah, dragging seems to be the only way.

Comment: @hepcat72, It may have, I really don't remember. All I know with the latest version I have on my iPhone it's DnD that works for me.